# Android EditText InputFilter

Tags: android, android-input-filter

How to delete two character at once with the filter?

I am trying to apply a simple filter to an EditText.
It must work as follows:
(want to receive format: 1234 5678....)

===> EDITED: First part works well.

1) when there are 4 digits in EditText and I am entering the 5-th digit -
first must appear a space and then this digit.
 2) And I need a reverse for this (during characters deletion) -
the space must be deleted with the 5-th digit.

What is wrong with my code?

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new DigitsKeyListener(Boolean.FALSE, Boolean.TRUE) {

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

        //  any chars except backspace
        if (!source.equals("")) {
            if (dest.length() == 4) {
                // here I must add a space and then the source
                // ===> EDITED:
                return " " + source;
                // return super.filter(" " + source, start, end + 1, dest, dstart, dend + 1);
            } // backspace entered
        } else {
            if (dest.length() == 6) {
                // here I must delete the 6-th character 
                // and the space before
                return super.filter(source, 0, 0, dest, 5, 6);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}});
```

Comment: what is the output of the above code? any error?

Comment: Outout is as if there are no filters: 1234567...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this

```
public class CustomFormatWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private int size;

    public CustomFormatWatcher(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        char hyphen = ' ';
        char c = 0;
        if (editable.length() > 0) {
            c = editable.charAt(editable.length() - 1);
            if (c == hyphen) {
                editable.delete(editable.length() - 1, editable.length());
            }
        }
        if (editable.length() > 0 && (editable.length() % size) == 0) {
            c = editable.charAt(editable.length() - 1);
            if (hyphen == c) {
                editable.delete(editable.length() - 1, editable.length());
            }
        }
        if (editable.length() > 0 && (editable.length() % size) == 0) {
            c = editable.charAt(editable.length() - 1);
            // Only if its a digit where there should be a space we insert a hyphen
            if (Character.isDigit(c) && TextUtils.split(editable.toString(), String.valueOf(hyphen)).length <= 3) {
                editable.insert(editable.length() - 1, String.valueOf(hyphen));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then use

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new CustomFormatWatcher());
```

Comment: Which size should I pass to new CustomFormatWatcher(int size)?

Comment: somehow it doesn't add the space between 4 and 5 character

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [`TextWatcher`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to format your `EditText` input, because `InputFilter` is generally used for input restrictions, to decides what can be typed not to format the text.

You'll get your desired output with this code:

```
String mTextValue;
Character mLastChar = '\0'; // init with empty character
int mKeyDel;

myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

           String eachBlock[] = myEditText.getText().toString().split(" ");

           myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)
                         mKeyDel = 1;
                         return false;
                   }
             });

            if (mKeyDel == 0) {

               if (((myEditText.getText().length() + 1) % 5) == 0) {
                   myEditText.setText(myEditText.getText() + " ");
                   myEditText.setSelection(myEditText.getText().length());
               }

               mTextValue = myEditText.getText().toString();

            } else {

               mTextValue = myEditText.getText().toString();

               if (mLastChar.equals(' ')) {
                    mTextValue = mTextValue.substring(0, mTextValue.length() - 1);
                    myEditText.setText(mTextValue);
                    myEditText.setSelection(mTextValue.length());
                }

               mKeyDel = 0;

            }

       }

       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            if (s.length()>0) {// save the last char value
                mLastChar = s.charAt(s.length() - 1);
            } else {
                mLastChar = '\0';
            }
       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

 });
```

Comment: Thanks. Why I can delete only one character in EditText?